# MUI X charts, long chart labels issue

Tags: material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-charts

Long labels on MUI X chart are being cut off.
I wonder is there any way to fix that behavior?
Like put '...' at the end of axis's label and show full string inside a tooltip (by hovering a specific bar)?

There is a screenshot of how it currently looks like (and shouldn't look like).
Any ideas?

CodeSandbox link attached - [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hopeful-wood-kk4wqp?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360007356gcuz2uz5q%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360003356gubdqndki%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360004356g057ym4yd%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360006356gjitv6osh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B55.73376015124007%252C44.26623984875993%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsf5dy360003356gubdqndki%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360002356gvzsy5xjs%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FDemo.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360003356gubdqndki%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360002356gvzsy5xjs%2522%257D%252C%2522clsf5dy360006356gjitv6osh%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360005356gf9yoja9b%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360006356gjitv6osh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360005356gf9yoja9b%2522%257D%252C%2522clsf5dy360004356g057ym4yd%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsf5dy360004356g057ym4yd%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A10%257D).

[image]

And below is how I want it to look like.

[image]

Tried to play with settings that the library offers us as well as changing the margins of chart container. Nothing seems to work well.

Comment: sandbox not working

Comment: @SimranSingh should work now

Answer (score 0):

You could add `margin: {{ right: 250 }}` to the chart component as documented on https://mui.com/x/react-charts/styling/#placement.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and just applied 5px padding:

```
<LineChart
                sx={{padding:'5px'}}
                width={550}
                height={300}
                series={[
                    { data: history.map(obj => obj.totalPaid), label: 'Total paid' },
                ]}
                xAxis={[{ scaleType: 'point', data: history.map(obj => obj.year) }]}
            />
```